# How to create RDD(Sub-Array[String]) from RDD(Array[String])?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

My initial RDD; Array[Array[String]], looks something like:

```
    a b h c ....... d e x q
    d r d x ....... e q g m
    f e u t ....... q t g y
    a b h c ....... d e x q
    d r d x ....... e q g m
    f e u t ....... q t g y
    ....
    ....
```

New RDD; Array[Array[String]], that contains:

```
u t ...... q t
h c ...... d e
```

Any idea on how to work on it? Size of the array is large, so one could want the sub-array of any size.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have function `bigToSmallArray` then you just have to do `rdd ofSmallArrays = rddOfBigArrays.map(bigToSmallArray)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you need here is just `drop*`:

```
rdd.map(_.drop(2).dropRight(2))
```

And if you're in doubt it is usually useful to check [Scala collections docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/introduction.html).

Comment: This works for the column. What if i want to select the rows, for example row(2) to row(8)?